# What's the easiest way for a user to create a transaction with 2 receiving addresses?

Tags: wallet, address

What's the easiest way for a user to create a transaction with 2 receiving addresses?

I'm not talking about "change".  Suppose I want to send 1 BTC to two addresses:
Alice 1KMkHaogstQ33Ea9k1rQuT5uduPPPQunT4 and 
Bob 123uibcSV7mTDSkzHi8pVaM4grLXxLfKre

Alice is supposed to get 0.9 BTC and Bob 0.1 BTC.
How can I do this in one transaction?

Is there a convenient way to make this happen from current (August 2013) Bitcoin client software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a built in feature of the reference Bitcoin-QT client. Make a transaction as normal, and click the [+] button to add a second recipient.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't used Bitcoin-Qt that much. I might have to rephrase my question then...